# Developing a driver for several Windows versions (xp, win7, vista)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, driver, 32bit-64bit, wdk

We are developing a DLL, which calls generic WinUsb functions from WinDDK. This DLL needs to work in 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, including xp, vista, win7, and possibly win8.

My question is, how can we manage the Visual Studio 2010 solution by targeting all these platforms? WinDDK libraries are different for each OS, so if I reference a library from the code:

```
#### #pragma comment (lib , "C:\\WinDDK\\7600.16385.1\\lib\\wlh\\i386\\winmm.lib" )
```

Or by referencing the library from the `project options->includes section`, this project only becomes correct for a particular target architecture. (In this example, Vista 32-bits, since I am including 'wlh').

Are we supposed to create a different project for each different OS target?

Comment: You are heading for a lot of trouble, you don't create DLLs with the ddk and you don't use VS.  Educate yourself with a book by Walter Oney.

Comment: @Hans: Perhaps my question was misleading. I am using VS to create a DLL, which calls generic WinUsb functions. In order to call the WinUsb functions, I reference the appropriate winusb.lib function from the DDK.

Comment: @SomethingBetter: Hans is right.  You're trying to call functions intended for drivers, and you're trying to do it using a development platform not intended for drivers.  You might or might not get away with this, but it's going to be a lot of trouble either way.

Answer (score 0):

The WDK/DDK version does not constrain the OS version for which you build. You can pass the target OS as a build environment/compile parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should build DLL through *DDK* and use that in your VS project.

You can write pre-build event for your VS project to run a batch file which will build the DLL and put it in some well-known place for the project.

Also, you may have to create different project configurations for each platform you want to build for (at least different for 32-bit and 64-bit) and run appropriate build command for DLL.